# Oracle Sequence generator syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

The basic syntax for creating a sequence generator for oracle database table attribute is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
START WITH     1000
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

I would like to know what does the `NOORDER` clause in the SEQUENCE syntax do? If I include the `NOORDER` clause, will it give me a sequence  keeping the increment value random???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is important when running in parallel server mode or in a cluster. ORDER guarantees that the sequences numbers are ordered.

```
Example of “noorder” sequence in 10g RAC:

Session 1 on node-A: nextval -> 101
Session 2 on node-A: nextval -> 102
Session 1 on node-B: nextval -> 121
Session 1 on node-B: nextval -> 122
Session 1 on node-A: nextval -> 103
Session 1 on node-A: nextval -> 104
```

NOORDER in combination with CACHING sequences results in this behavior. ORDER effectively makes the CACHE setting unused. With caching set to 10 when a session gets a sequences it takes 10 sequences into it's cache.

Comment: Okay, I get some idea. But, is the NOORDER clause only associated to the SESSION through which the record was inserted!! Also, what decides the increment of the value on the other session. In this case, what decided the value in the next session to be `121`???

Comment: NOORDER in combination with CACHING sequences results in this behavior. ORDER effectively makes the CACHE setting unused. With caching set to 10 when a session gets a sequences it takes 10 sequences into it's cache.

Comment: Does using `CACHE` guarantee the behavior you mentioned above? I have a table with `CACHE = 20` which generated a totally random sequence! Is there any specific reason for this behavior.

Also, can I use both `CACHE` and `ORDER` at the same time? Will this generate values in a proper sequence??

Comment: Sunmit, are you on RAC? sequences aren't "random" but can seem to be a bit if the "cache" is set and noorder too on RAC when you're using 2+ nodes to select values. Yes you can use CACHE + ORDER at the same time, and its significantly better to do so vs "nocache order". just remember that the performance of a sequence is fastest at "cache noorder" then "cache order" and a long way behind is "nocache" (order is irrelevant in this setting).